# How to get the object name as a string inside a function in r

Tags: r, function, assign

I want to change column names of a data frame with a function.

To overwrite my data frame with the new column names, I used assign(), which first argument has to be the name of the same data frame as a string. To get the name as a string, I used deparse(substitute(x)), which worked outside the function. But inside the function, it returns the content of my data frame as a string instead of the name itself...

```
df <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:5), 
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

deparse(substitute(df))

rename_fun <- function(x) {
  colnames(x)[1] <- "___0"
  colnames(x)[2] <- "___1"

  y <- deparse(substitute(x))
  
    assign(y, x, envir = .GlobalEnv)      
}

rename_fun(df)
```

I also tried

```
as.character(substitute(x))
```

but the same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to use `as.character(match.call()$x)`, which can be used at any point in the function:

```r
rename_fun <- function(x) {
  colnames(x)[1] <- "___0"
  colnames(x)[2] <- "___1"
  assign(as.character(match.call()$x), x, envir = .GlobalEnv)      
}
```

Giving

```r
rename_fun(df)

df
#>   ___0     ___1
#> 1    1     Rick
#> 2    2      Dan
#> 3    3 Michelle
#> 4    4     Ryan
#> 5    5     Gary
```

Note though that functions which write objects into the global environment as a side effect are not recommended, even if they are overwriting an existing object. A function should return the altered data frame, which the user may then *choose* to use to overwrite the object.

A better way to write the function would be:

```r
rename_fun <- function(x) {
  
  colnames(x)[1] <- "___0"
  colnames(x)[2] <- "___1"
  x
}
```

Which would be called like this:

```
df <- rename_fun(df)
```

And give the same result, while leaving the option of having a copy of the original data frame if the caller wants.

<sup>Created on 2022-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We need to use `deparse/substitute` at the start of the function

```
rename_fun <- function(x) {
 y <- deparse(substitute(x))
  colnames(x)[1] <- "___0"
  colnames(x)[2] <- "___1" 
  
  assign(y, x, envir = .GlobalEnv)      
}
```

-testing

```
> rename_fun(df)
> df
  ___0     ___1
1    1     Rick
2    2      Dan
3    3 Michelle
4    4     Ryan
5    5     Gary
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! But why do I have to use deparse() at the start of the function? (Just to know)